# Reading a computed property injected by a service with handlebars in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to mutate my handlebars scripts by using a computed `isAuthenticated` property injected via a custom auth service. In the `my-application` component, this works with little problem via the following code:

```
      {{#if isAuthenticated}}
        <li>{{#link-to "accounts.my-account"}}My Account{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to "accounts.search-accounts"}}Find other Medici Users{{/link-to}}</li>
      {{/if}}

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  auth: Ember.inject.service(),
  user: Ember.computed.alias('auth.credentials.email'),
  isAuthenticated: Ember.computed.alias('auth.isAuthenticated'),

  actions: {
    signOut () {
      this.sendAction('signOut');
    },
  },
});
```

When I try to implement this exact same code in a different location (in this case, the accounts route) as such:

```
<button type="btn" {{action "test"}}>test</button>

{{#if isAuthenticated}}
<p>test</p>
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  auth: Ember.inject.service(),
  user: Ember.computed.alias('auth.credentials.email'),
  isAuthenticated: Ember.computed.alias('auth.isAuthenticated'),

  actions: {
    test () {
      console.log(this.get('user'));
      console.log(this.get('isAuthenticated'));
    }
  }
});
```

There is no change in the template (though test does appear when you switch the `if` out with an `unless`). Making this all the stranger is the fact that, when I click the `test` button, it successfully fires the result of isAuthenticated. Why am I unable to transfer this property over from my js file to my hbs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the property in a controller; is there a controller for the accounts route? Props on the route (other than `model`) aren't directly visible to the template.

An alternative would be to create a component which wraps the accounts template; you could inject the auth service in there instead of a controller if you don't want one or want to keep it small.

Note that one thing our team does is automatically inject the auth service (or rather, the equivalent session service) into all components; you can do this with an initializer. That reduces boilerplate somewhat.

Comment: The template I'm using does not seem to have access to controllers. However, My situation has actually just managed to get a little stranger. I'll update my issue w/the details.

Comment: "The template I'm using does not seem to have access to controllers"  - that doesn't really make sense, but perhaps that route doesn't have a controller yet? They're not required in Ember, you need to create one when you need it.

Comment: perhaps you need to use the ember inspector to debug a little; otherwise, perhaps your `auth` service isn't working as expected.

Comment: Actually, I just managed to getting it working. Not entirely sure why, but your advice to strictly focus on the components was largely successful. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I'm using a pre-configured template from a school. In their configuration/teaching of ember, controllers were left off the agenda. I am thus hesitant to touch them.